# XCUItest is not passing even though predicates seem valid

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

Here is my code -> https://github.com/patchthecode/XCTestBug

Here is my view ->

[image]

I am trying to capture the gray colored view.
It contains a label `Ll` and  Button `11`

This code captures the view

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE[c] %@","L1")
let views = app.otherElements.containing(p1)
```

This code also captures the view correctly

```
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE[c] %@","11")
let views = app.otherElements.containing(p2)
```

But this code fails to capture anything

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE[c] %@","L1")
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE[c] %@","11")

let comp = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
let views = app.otherElements.containing(comp)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `comp` predicate would work, it would not capture the gray view. It would capture all elements that contain the "L1" and the "11" element. In your case it captures 2 elements: the `ViewController`'s view and the gray view (because both contain the "L1" and the "11". So this is not the right way to capture the gray view.

The easiest part to capture the gray view would be to add an accessibility identifier to it (and enable Accessibility for that `UIView`). Then you can query the gray box easily with:

```
let grayBox = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "grayBox").element(boundBy: 0)
```

Your `NSCompoundPredicate` solution does not work because the query is looking for elements that contain **ONE** label with the text "L1" **AND** "11". And because a UILabel can only have one text this always fails.